# preventing fantomide from exporting libs

Tags: fantom

I need to use [fantom](http://fantom.org/) for a University project. I downloaded the fantom environment, and [fantomIDE](http://fantomide.colar.net/home) to go with it. It all works great.

My problem:

I have created a project named test to test some things and check all goes and runs. When I checked the fantom installation folders I fond a file named after my test project, and running it resulted with the test code.

I don't want every class I create to be exported to the installation folder of fantom (mostly because I don't want to crowd the name space with to many pods).

Is this by design? Can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: It's not every *class* that gets exported to the installation folder, just one .pod file per project. More is said in [Build & Run a Fantom App](http://fantom-factory.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/build-and-run-fantom-app.html#.UwR_Qjd_sak)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a blank file called `fan.props` to the root directory of your project folder.  This is a non-documented shortcut to create a [PathEnv](http://fantom.org/doc/docLang/Env.html).

You can verify your setup by doing a `fan -version`:

```
andy:~/proj/draft$ fan -version
Fantom Launcher
Copyright (c) 2006-2013, Brian Frank and Andy Frank
Licensed under the Academic Free License version 3.0

Java Runtime:
  java.version:    1.6.0_65
  java.vm.name:    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
  java.vm.vendor:  Apple Inc.
  java.vm.version: 20.65-b04-462
  java.home:       /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
  fan.platform:    macosx-x86_64
  fan.version:     1.0.65
  fan.env:         util::PathEnv
  fan.home:        /Users/andy/proj/fantom/dev

Env Path:
  /Users/andy/proj/draft (work)
  /Users/andy/proj/fantom/dev (home)
```

Comment: A [PathEnv](http://fantom.org/doc/docLang/Env.html#PathEnv) is definitely the way to go, as the build will then save the .pod in the work dir. But I don't know if `PathEnv` will work with FantomIDE. If  `fan.props` doesn't work, then I'd try the usual ENV variables.